# Why can't I seem to access elements of a multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath, var-dump

I have an XML file that was converted into an array with xpath. Ultimately I want to be able to access the variables in the array but no method seems to work.

`echo $items['member']['name'];` Does not work
`echo $items['name'];` Nor this
`echo $items['members']['member']['name'];` Nor this
`echo $items[0][0]` Nor this
`echo $items[0]` Nor this
`echo $items[0]['object']['name']`Nor this
`$items[0]['name']`Nor this

I have no no what the problem is but I imagine it might be with xpath and it's effect on the array. I understand that there are other similar threads but no resource seems to help.

**PHP:**

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('XML/profiles.xml'); //Create XML variable from XML file.

    $items = $xml->xpath('member');

    var_dump($items);
    ?>
```

**XML:**

```
    <member>
        <name>AndrewHarvey</name>
        <location>Carleton-Victoria</location>
        <party>L</party>
    </member>

    <member>
        <name>BenoitBourque</name>
        <location>Kent North</location>
        <party>L</party>
    </member>

    <member>
        <name>BernardLeBlanc</name>
        <location>Memramcook-Tantramar</location>
        <party>L</party>
    </member>

    <member>
        <name>BertrandLeBlanc</name>
        <location>Kent North</location>
        <party>L</party>
    </member>

    <member>
        <name>BillFraser</name>
        <location>Miramichi</location>
        <pos>Tourism</pos>
        <pos>Heritage and Culture</pos>
        <pos>Northern and Miramichi Funds</pos>
        <party>L</party>
    </member>
and so on...
```

**Var dump of $array:**

```
array (size=49)  
      0 =>   
      object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]  
      public 'name' => string 'AndrewHarvey' (length=12)  
      public 'location' => string 'Carleton-Victoria' (length=17)  
      public 'party' => string 'L' (length=1)  
  1 =>   
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]  
      public 'name' => string 'BenoitBourque' (length=13)  
      public 'location' => string 'Kent North' (length=10)  
      public 'party' => string 'L' (length=1)  
  2 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
      public 'name' => string 'BernardLeBlanc' (length=14)
      public 'location' => string 'Memramcook-Tantramar' (length=20)
      public 'party' => string 'L' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
      public 'name' => string 'BertrandLeBlanc' (length=15)
      public 'location' => string 'Kent North' (length=10)
      public 'party' => string 'L' (length=1)
  4 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
      public 'name' => string 'BillFraser' (length=10)
      public 'location' => string 'Miramichi' (length=9)
      public 'pos' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'Tourism' (length=7)
          1 => string 'Heritage and Culture' (length=20)
          2 => string 'Northern and Miramichi Funds' (length=28)
and so on...
```

Comment: these are Objects, so use `->` to access the member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is an Object array, so you need the `->` to access them. Using the foreach you can access the array.

```
foreach($items as $val){
    echo $val->name;
    echo $val->location;
    echo $val->party;
}
```

Try this and let me know. If anything else in the array, you need to do it similar way.

Comment: It works, thank you! So this is not simply a multidimensional array? Just a regular array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comment Frayne Konok made you could access those values like this:
`$name = array[0] -> name;`

You could also loop through each of them as:

```
foreach ($node as $index => $data)
{
   $name = $data -> name;
   $location = $data -> location;

   if (property_exists($data, 'party'))
   { $party = $data -> party; }       

   if (property_exists($data, 'pos'))
   { $pos_attr = $data -> pos[0]; }
}
```

Little disclaimer here... I didn't test this so you would want to play around with this, but you get the idea.

The **array** at the top of your var_dump there denotes that the outer wrapping is an array and would need to be accessed like one. The **object(SimpleXMLElement)** underneath each of those entries denotes that the items in that array are objects and would have to be accessed as such. The **array (size=3)** under the **poc** attribute denotes that it's an array. You can see where I'm going with this. Arrays are accessed using bracket notation `array[0]` or `array['example']` and objects are accessed using arrow notation `object -> name` or `object -> {'0'}` (in odd cases).

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` always returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects. It is not a multidimensional or nested array. However `SimpleXMLElement` implements a lot of syntax sugar. One of that is array syntax for attributes.

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo attr="bar"/>');
echo $element['attr'];
```

But to access child nodes, you need to use object syntax.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('XML/profiles.xml');

foreach ($xml->xpath('member') as $member) {
  echo $member->name;
}
```

The `var_dump()` output of a `SimpleXMLElement` is not a full/correct representation of the actual object, because of the syntax sugar. For example you can iterate the SimpleXMLElement properties, too.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('XML/profiles.xml');

foreach ($xml->member as $member) {
  echo $member->name;
}
```